# Qt, implicit shared object, what happens on delete?

Tags: c++, qt

```
//Case 1:
QImage* tImg = new QImage("Some Image Here");
painter->drawImage(x, y, *tImg );
...
delete tImg;

//Case 2:
QImage* tImg = new QImage("Some Image Here");
{
    QImage aImg(*tImg);
    painter->drawImage(x, y, aImg );
}
...
delete tImg;
```

QImage is implicitly shared, when something (like the `aImg`) get a "shared copy" of the original data, what will happen if I delete the original data, will the `aImg` still preserve the data?

And what happens to case 1, will drawImage create a shared copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit sharing in Qt follows the CoW (copy on write) paradigm - objects will implicitly share the same internal resource as long as it is not modified, if some of the copies attempts to modify the resource, it will be "detached" from the shared resource, copy it and apply the modifications to it.

When object lifetime ends, it decrements the reference counter for the shared resource, and if it is zero that means no other object uses it, so it is deleted. If the reference count is more than zero, the resource remains alive until there are objects, referencing it.

In case 1 the shared resource will be deleted, as there are no more objects referencing it.

In case 2 it will be deleted as well, because `aImg` will be out of scope by the time `tImg` is deleted.

Comment: Then will there be any problem on the drawImage() function? since it takes  an (const QImage & image) as input. Is it ok to delete the QImage reference after calling drawImage()?

Comment: `drawImage()` will not modify the image, so it will remain referencing the shared resource. There is no problem with deleting it, as the painting operation itself will copy the pixel values to the target paint device. The paint device will not be referencing the image data, but even if it did and it used CoW, the data would stay alive as long as needed.

Comment: Is the copy of pixel values happening immediately? If `delete tImg` is on another thread (but I do use mutex to make sure the `delete tImg` is called after the call of `drawImage()` ), will it still be safe?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that if your paint device is a widget, drawing must happen in its paint event, otherwise it won't work. The reference counting itself is atomic, so you can delete `tImg` in another thread and `aImg` will still have the data.

Comment: Now if you only have one image, and it is possible that it may be deleted from another thread you should implement some manual thread safety.

Comment: I did so with QMutex which make sure the `delete tImg` is called after the call of `drawImage(x, y, tImg)`, (Here `tImg` referes to the same pointer) is it safe enough?

Comment: As long as all access to the image goes through the mutex

Comment: Can I say that the thing to take care is to not passing the drawImage() a deleted bad pointer?

Comment: You definitely don't want to do that, it's common sense.